# Python socket get stuck when printing

Tags: python, python-sockets

program 1:

```
print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8))
```

program 2:

```
response=client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
 print(response)
 # rest of the code
```

program 1 works fine but program 2 is stucking

the second program is printing the response and I except it to continue after that but it stuck there after the print, can someone explain what is happening here? also printing after send do the same thing

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.